# Does cooling the skin reduce irritation from shaving?

Tags: dermatology, technology, shaving-razor-burn, aftershave, shave-shaving

Increasing age has increased the sensitivity of my grandfather's skin; so he asked me to pose the question entitled above, after seeing [electronic shavers that cool the skin](http://www.braun.com/global/male-grooming/cooltec-shavers/cooltec-shaver-models.html) and questioning whether they would improve his shaves. Disclaimer: No, I am not connected with Braun in any way.